# R data.table: How to calculate ratio of sum of values, for columns from vector, within the group, vs. the rest of the values in the columns in table?

Tags: r, data.table

Let say we have a DT:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 7 |
| 3 | 5 | 9 |
| 3 | 6 | 11 |

Let's say we want to obtain the ratio of mean value of B and C within each group A c(1,2,3) to mean values of B and C but for all other groups A (=exluding the group A)...

Let's say the "columns to calculate mean" = _vars = c(B,C).

What if I am grouping by A and C and _vars = c(B) only ?
Update:

How to do it automatically for all column names in a given vector, i.e. c("B","C")

Comment: I think that your explanation is different from what you are actually doing in your code. In your code, you are using the global mean while in your explanation, you talked about the mean in all _other_ groups. Do you want to divide the mean of each group by the global mean or the mean for all other groups? example: consider column B and group 1 in A. do you want to divide the mean of c(1, 2) by the mean of c(1,2,3,4,5,6) or by the mean of c(3,4,5,6)? Further, the group variable is A in your explanation but in your code, it seems to be B. Could you make it clear?(Did I misunderstand something?)

Comment: You are right, I was too excited, yes I want to group by A (1) and calculate mean of B and also B for that group versus all other groups (2 and 3)....

Comment: What's automatic? calculating the ratios of means for all columns in _vars or calculating the ratios of means for all possible groups in _vars?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly:

```
cols<-c('A','C')
cols.remaining <- setdiff(colnames(dt),cols) 

global.means <- paste0("GlobalMean",cols.remaining)
group.means <- paste0("GroupMean",cols.remaining)
group.ratios <- paste0("GroupRatio",cols.remaining)


dt[, (global.means):= lapply(.SD, mean) ,.SDcols=c(cols.remaining)][
   ,(group.means) := lapply(.SD, mean), by = cols,.SDcols=cols.remaining][
   ,(group.ratios):= mapply(group.means,global.means,FUN = function(m,g) get(m)/get(g),SIMPLIFY = F)][]

   A B  C GlobalMeanB GroupMeanB GroupRatioB
1: 1 1  1         3.5          1   0.2857143
2: 1 2  3         3.5          2   0.5714286
3: 2 3  5         3.5          3   0.8571429
4: 2 4  7         3.5          4   1.1428571
5: 3 5  9         3.5          5   1.4285714
6: 3 6 11         3.5          6   1.7142857
```

and with `cols <- c('B')`:

```
   A B  C GlobalMeanA GlobalMeanC GroupMeanA GroupMeanC GroupRatioA GroupRatioC
1: 1 1  1           2           6          1          1         0.5   0.1666667
2: 1 2  3           2           6          1          3         0.5   0.5000000
3: 2 3  5           2           6          2          5         1.0   0.8333333
4: 2 4  7           2           6          2          7         1.0   1.1666667
5: 3 5  9           2           6          3          9         1.5   1.5000000
6: 3 6 11           2           6          3         11         1.5   1.8333333
6: 3 11 0.28571429
```

Comment: Hi thanks for inspiration with chaining, but please see my follow up update in the question stem.

Comment: Could you `dput` the data you're using? Example you provided doesn't have `Customer_ID`

Comment: Sorry, I corrected... I really can't :(

Comment: See my edit for multile columns

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear, forgive me and thank you for your patience. So I want to calculate the ratio of mean value B for all groups one by one as per A : mean of all values B which are not in the same group as per A

Comment: Could you give an example of expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way to solve your problem.

```
# ratios of means related to column B and C grouped by A
cols = c("B", "C")
DT[, Map(`/`, lapply(.SD, mean), lapply(DT[-.I, cols, with=FALSE], mean)), by=.(A), .SDcols=cols]
#        A         B     C
# 1:     1 0.3333333  0.25
# 2:     2 1.0000000  1.00
# 3:     3 2.2000000  2.50

# alternative solution (gives the same result)
DT[, Map(`/`, lapply(.SD, mean), lapply(DT[!.BY, cols, with=FALSE, on=.(A)], mean)), by=.(A), .SDcols=cols]
```

`lapply(.SD, mean)` computes the groups' means.
`lapply(DT[-.I, cols, with=FALSE], mean)`: computes the means excluding the current group.
`Map` function then uses the division operator, `/`, to compute the ratio between the groups' means (calculated by `lapply(.SD, mean)`) and the means excluding the current group (calculated by `lapply(DT[-.I, cols, with=FALSE], mean)`) element-wise.

For other scenarios, you just adapt the `.SDcols` and `by` arguments in an appropriate way.

```
# ratios of means related to column B grouped by A and C.
cols = "B"
DT[, Map(`/`, lapply(.SD, mean), lapply(DT[-.I, cols, with=FALSE], mean)), by=.(A, C), .SDcols=cols]
#        A     C         B
# 1:     1     1 0.2500000
# 2:     1     3 0.5263158
# 3:     2     5 0.8333333
# 4:     2     7 1.1764706
# 5:     3     9 1.5625000
# 6:     3    11 2.0000000
```